# ¿Es posible una app que se mantenga activa todo el tiempo en AppleTv?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, swift4, swiftui

Estoy creando una app en donde muestro un mapa y diferentes ubicaciones en swift sacadas de socket para appleTV, es posible hacer que esa app esté activa todo el tiempo?
Ya que mi resultado final lo eh probado en una appleTv y en simuladores de Xcode, pero en ambos casos mi app termina cerrándose automáticamente mientras mi tv sigue encendido.
Quisiera saber si es posible eso o si necesito hacer algo extra para lograr ese resultado

Comment: Apple no deja que nada este activado todo el tiempo, todo tiene limitaciones.